# Spring Boot Application using Spring Boot Legacy gives NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, jonas

We are using spring boot to develop a REST application that we will be deploying on JOnAS 5.x which is a servlet 2.5 container. We used Spring Boot Legacy taking help from [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html). The application works fine with embedded tomcat but when we deploy this application on JOnAS 5.x via eclispe it gives the error as below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
```

Our pom.xml is as below

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.shilipi.rest</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringBootRest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-legacy</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <!-- Package as an executable jar -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>


    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

web.xml is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.shilpi.rest.configuration.Application</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.SpringBootContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>metricFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>metricFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Application Configuration as below:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.shilpi.rest.configuration")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Link for [Spring boot legacy](https://github.com/dsyer/spring-boot-legacy). I searched extensively on internet but didn't get any related answer for it. If anyone could please help.

Comment: Have you tried with the latest version of spring-boot-legacy, 1.1.1.RELEASE?

Comment: Yes I checked with the version 1.1.0.RELEASE, but stil it didnt work.

Comment: Have you tried using a version of Spring Boot that Spring Boot Legacy supports? (e.g.1.1.0.RELEASE supports Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE)

Comment: Hi @MarkMcLaren , Yes I did check with that. But Couldn't get it up and decided to build the REST API with JAX-RS- Jersey.